# Paypal sandbox always returns blank page?

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I have set up a demo account in `Paypal` and in `woocommerece` set it on sandbox.
Then every time I proceed to pay with `Paypal` test account he goes to a sandbox url and show a *blank* page.

No matter how many times I tried, what browser, it's been 2 days like this.

Even tried *incognito* mode on Chrome, without success.

I have set up on the website :

```
PAYPAL IDENTITY TOKEN
API SIGNATURE
API USER NAME
API PASSWORD
```

Comment: Yea... -1 god knows why. So stupid people. A serious problem without any solution, but someone decided it's not good enough for him.

Comment: Same here. Wish I could find a status page for that. So I could decide where to invest my time.

Comment: (not using woocommerce, but drupal commerce) Looking at the POST reply header, I am getting a code 500 error (Internal Server Error) instead of a page from sandbox.paypal.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting this as an answer but I don't have comment privileges. I also have been getting this for a few days. The Chrome browser Network tools shows the PayPal server response as 500 Internal Server Error. So I checked with https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search and it shows that on June 1 and June 18 that the sandbox was returning this error. However, PayPal says that the June 18 problem was resolved on June 21. I previously used the sandbox successfully about a month ago and I don't think I have changed anything that would have changed the PayPal request. This is just what I have found out about this problem don't really know if it means that the server is currently having a problem.

Comment: Thank you ! so now you can or you cant do it ?

Comment: Oh you can't comment I guess :) so maybe write it in your answer.

Comment: Actually, I have been working on something else so this was true yesterday. I will try again later today but not right now. I will comment here when I have tried again.

Comment: Just tried again still sandbox returns 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: If you haven't changed anything then it must be something with paypal, you might want to take a look at it: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Those changes were completed last October. I have used the PayPal sandbox successfully many, many times since then. The last time only a month ago.  Anyway, I am not getting a SSL error but a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. The request that is failing is being sent by the Chrome browser so it is using the certificate store that the Chrome browser is using which I am assuming is up to date(?). This same problem occurred on Jun 18 and PayPal did not report it fixed until Jun 21 - three days so I am surmising maybe it is the same problem. Anyway, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yup, I get a "your connection is not secure error" now when it was previously working flawlessly

Comment: Are you using IPN? I use PDT since that does not use a direct connection from my WooCommerce server to the PayPal server. Since, the server to server communications are done indirectly through the browser it uses the browser's SSL facilities and not the WooCommerce SSL facilities.

Answer (score 1):

This error is on paypal demo site also. I have posted it on paypal forum also.
See:
https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/navigation?merchant=beauty&page=product
choose sandbox and see the same 500 error.

Comment: Issue has been fixed by paypal. They have changed the ui also. :)