# PayPal Standard payment sandbox showing blank page

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PayPal standard payment and using following code.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Sasha">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="545.71">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<merchant-email-id>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="0"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="48"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="test11">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="test21">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<buyer-email-id>">
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="Santa clara">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Santa clara">
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="CA">
    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="95050">
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="USA">
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="1023456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<complete-url>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<complete-url>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<complete-url>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I press submit and go to PayPal sandbox screen then it shows blank page. Is it under maintenance or there could be issue from my end. Few days earlier same above form was working but from last 3-4 days PayPal sandbox page showing blank.

I am not getting is it problem from my end or their end?

Comment: Same thing happens to me. It displays Internal server error in console.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744021/paypal-sandbox-always-returns-blank-page).

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hat">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="9 Elm Street">
  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Apt 5">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Berwyn">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19312">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="610">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="555">
  <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1234">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="jdoe@zyzzyu.com">
  <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
Link:- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

Note:- Please above link and use this form. And check results or check below form


<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Memorex 256MB Memory Stick">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="MEM32507725">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3">
  <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

  <!-- Enable override of buyers's address stored with PayPal . -->
  <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">
  <!-- Set variables that override the address stored with PayPal. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="345 Lark Ave">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="San Jose">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="CA">
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="95121">
  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
  <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

Comment: he use `sandbox` not `live`.

Comment: So you can change its url
check link live to sandbox: - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/

Comment: Can you read question? He use `sandbox` a/c and it's not working.

Comment: Yes Jaydeep, you are right. My problem is with sandbox. In live mode it is already working fine.